# How to kill many geckodriver.exe processes?

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I am using Windows 10 pro x64, Firefox 50.x, Java 8, Selenium 3.0.1

```
public RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver;

//...

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", browserWebDriverFilePath);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
remoteWebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
remoteWebDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
remoteWebDriver.manage().window().maximize();

//...

remoteWebDriver.quit();
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run this from Command line:

```
taskkill /F /IM geckodriver.exe
```

Or better of, put it in a batch file and run the file every time you want to clean up.

You can also do it from your code if you want, before you start running:

```
boolean isDebug = java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().toString().indexOf("-agentlib:jdwp") > 0;
try {
    if (isDebug)
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM geckodriver.exe");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Only in debug to avoid killing instances on slave if you're running in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered this problem with webdriver which was leaving many zombie geckodriver processes.

Placing the driver.quit() in finally block resolves this problem.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addArguments("--headless");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);

try {

   .... 

} finally {
   driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if driver.Close() and the execute driver.Quit(), this way not succes but overide driver.Close() with driver.Quit()

Not exec with terminal because will leave  process in the server.